# How tolerant are cuccos?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

How many hits on a cucco from the master sword does it take to initiate the cucco swarm attack? I have hit a cucco once by mistake, and it didn't trigger, but I want to be sure to have a margin of safety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ocarina of Time, the cuccos can take three strikes before the swarm attack.

[Source](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Cucco)